# Are questions related to steganography or watermarking on topic here?

Tags: discussion

I am a mathematician, and I have no problem figuring out the programming part when I try to read steganographic approaches on IEEE. So, I thought my questions do not fit stackoverflow. I am a newbie in DSP and sometimes it is very hard for me to understand an article since algorithms in publications are denoted using DSP notations. Wavelet transforms, cepstral analysis, correlation, convolution, etc, I have an endless will to learn whatever I come across on publications to be able to understand every single line.

I see that here everyone try to help each other despite their crazy daily routines. However, I feel like questions are ignored (less viewed comparing to other questions) which are related to steganography.

So, I was wondering if questions about steganography should be asked here. If not, where is it best place to go for?

Answer (score 1):

Try [crypto.stackexchange.com](http://crypto.stackexchange.com), it seems to give the most hits when googling *steganography site:stackexchange.com*, with [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/) following.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already visited crypto.se and security.se, but what I am interested in is audio steganography/watermarking, and as I mentioned above I am stuck especially when I come across DSP notations. I just didn't know where to go, so wanted to give a try asking for suggestions.